# How does one go from a couple of DNA sequences to a distance-matrix?

Tags: population-genetics, phylogenetics

For a project we need to explain the subject of UPGMA. 
We think we understand thee method itself but I fail to see how you go from a number of DNA-sequences to the distance matrix.

I understand that the lower the number, the more related two species but on what scale is this number and how to interpret the exact meaning of this number. 
For example if the number between A and B is 17 what does that mean?